# Photoshop color profiles and saving for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profiles

I'm looking for the definitive answer to what color profiles should be used when it pertains to working with graphics and saving graphics for the web.

What color profiles is everyone using while in photoshop? sRGB?

Under View > Proof Setup what color profiles are selected there? Also should I be using View > Proof Colors?

It seems that no matter how hard I try I am creating graphics that I save for the web and they are coming out over saturated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the colour layout you wish to use, if they change when published, while not photoshop some of these articles should help (they have links to tool sites).
Choosing the correct [colour palette](http://thedesignmag.com/27-color-tools-and-resource-for-choosing-the-right-color-palette.html)
Visibone has an online service to test [contrasts of colours.](http://www.visibone.com/)
Infomation above is a copy and paste from a search of 'color' + enter [at Pro WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14034/how-to-tune-up-colors-in-web-page)
You may be better served at one of these SuperUser - sister sites
[Pro WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions)
[Graphics Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions)